# Could explain me the following property of the mean value?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could explain me the following property of the mean value?

> Let $u$ be a function that satisfies the Laplace equation at a disc that is continuous at the boundary of the disc. Then the value of $u$ at the center of the disc is equal with the average of its values on the circle.

Comment: What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: @IlikeSerena Could explain me the sentence: $$\text{Then the value of u at the center of the disc is equal with the average of its values on the circle.}$$

Comment: How would you calculate the average of a function?

Comment: @IlikeSerena There is the theorem: Let $f:[a,b] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then $\exists \xi \in [a,b]$ such that $$\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b{f}=f(\xi)$$ Is that the way to calculate the average of a function?

Comment: Yes. It's an application of the average of a function though. $\ddot \smile$ An average is usually $\frac 1 n \sum f_i$. Applied to a function it becomes a Riemann integral, which is what you have there. Applied to a circle, it becomes what I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a function $u(r,\theta)$ on the disc with radius $R$.
Then the value at the center of the disc is:
$$u(0,0)$$
The average of its values on the circle is:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi R}\int_{\text{circle}} u(R, \theta(s)) ds = \frac{1}{2\pi R}\int_0^{2\pi} u(R, \theta) R d\theta$$
Your theorem says that these are the same when $u$ is a solution of the Laplace equation.

Comment: I understand now the average. Thanks for explaining!!! Could you also explain me the meaning of the fact that $u$ should be a solution of the Laplace equation so that these are the same?

Comment: It's a property of a solution of the Laplace equation: *if* $u$ is a solution of the Laplace equation, the center of the disk is equal to the average of the edge of the disk. For a proof I refer to your other thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759227/question-about-poisson-formula

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)